# Fetching reminders from calendars in Swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, race-condition, reminders, ekeventstore

What's the thread-safe way of fetching Reminders from various calendars? I'm just trying to count all reminders and print them. The printing works but the counting doesn't. Is there a race-condition because fetching reminders is asynchronous?

```
func loadFromCalendars(cals: [EKCalendar], completed: (NSError?)->()) {
    // STEP 1 OF CREATING AN OVERALL COMPLETION BLOCK: Create a dispatch group.
    let loadCalendarServiceGroup: dispatch_group_t = dispatch_group_create()

    // Define errors to be processed when everything is complete.
    // One error per service; in this example we'll have two
    let configError: NSError? = nil
    let preferenceError: NSError? = nil

    var reminderCounter = 0


    let eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()
    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion: {
        granted, error in
        if (granted) && (error == nil) {
            print("granted \(granted)")
            print("error  \(error)")
        }
    })

    // Go through calendars.
    for cal in cals {
        let remindersPredicate = eventStore.predicateForRemindersInCalendars([cal])

        // STEP 2 OF CREATING AN OVERALL COMPLETION BLOCK: Adding tasks to a dispatch group
        dispatch_group_enter(loadCalendarServiceGroup)

        eventStore.fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate(remindersPredicate) {
            // MARK: Begininning of thread

            reminders in

            _ = (reminders!).map {

                // TRYING TO COUNT HERE THE REMINDERS. ALWAYS PRINTS 0!
                reminder -> EKReminder in
                print(reminder.title)
                reminderCounter += 1
                return reminder

            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.sendChangedNotification()  // refreshes the UI
            }
        }


        // STEP 3 OF CREATING AN OVERALL COMPLETION BLOCK: Leave dispatch group. This must be done at the end of the completion block.
        dispatch_group_leave(loadCalendarServiceGroup)

        // MARK: End of thread
    }


    // STEP 4 OF CREATING AN OVERALL COMPLETION BLOCK: Acting when the group is finished
    dispatch_group_notify(loadCalendarServiceGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        print("************ reminder count: \(reminderCounter) ****************")


        // Assess any errors
        var overallError: NSError? = nil;

        if configError != nil || preferenceError != nil {
            // Either make a new error or assign one of them to the overall error. Use '??', which is the "nil Coalescing Operator". It's syntactic sugar for the longer expression:
            //     overallError = configError != nil ? configError : preferenceError
            overallError = configError ?? preferenceError
        }            // Now call the final completion block


        // Call the completed function passed to loadCalendarHelper. This will contain the stuff that I want executed in the end.
        completed(overallError)
    })
}
```

**EDIT**
Thanks for the great tips, jtbandes! I simplified my code (a lot!) One question - I'm chaining some functions that change the resulting data structure. How can I make in the below code groupArrayBy() thread-safe?

```
public extension SequenceType {
    /// Categorises elements of self into a dictionary, with the keys given by keyFunc       
    func groupArrayBy<U : Hashable>(@noescape keyFunc: Generator.Element -> U) -> [U:[Generator.Element]] {
        var dict: [U:[Generator.Element]] = [:]
        for el in self {
            let key = keyFunc(el)
            if case nil = dict[key]?.append(el) { dict[key] = [el] }
        }
        return dict
    }
}


func loadFromCalendars(cals: [EKCalendar], completed: (NSError?)->()) {
    let configError: NSError? = nil
    let preferenceError: NSError? = nil

    withEstore {        // retrieves the EKEventStore
        estore in
        let predicate = estore.predicateForRemindersInCalendars(cals)
        estore.fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate(predicate) { reminders in
            print("Number of reminders: \(reminders?.count ?? 0)")  // Prints correct result

            let list = (reminders!).map {
                // this map still works, it seems thread-safe
                reminder -> ReminderWrapper in
                return ReminderWrapper(reminder: reminder)  // This still works. ReminderWrapper is just a wrapper class. Not very interesting...
                }.groupArrayBy { $0.reminder.calendar }     // ERROR: groupArrayBy doesn't seem to be thread-safe!

            print("Number of reminders: \(Array(list.values).count)")   // Prints a too low count. Proves that groupArrayBy isn't thread-safe.

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.sendChangedNotification()  // refreshes the UI

                completed(configError ?? preferenceError)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few changes should be made to this code:

1. `dispatch_group_leave(loadCalendarServiceGroup)` must be ***inside*** the `fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate` block. Otherwise, the block you passed to `dispatch_group_notify` will execute before the fetches are finished, which entirely defeats the purpose of using a group.
2. The `requestAccessToEntityType` call is also asynchronous, but your code simply continues after starting the access request, without waiting for it to finish. You might want to chain your completion blocks together.
3. You're requesting access to the `.Event` type, but you probably want `.Reminder`.
4. `reminderCounter += 1` is not thread-safe. You might want to `dispatch_async` onto a serial queue before changing the counter (so there is no contention between threads), or you could use the [OSAtomicAdd family](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW14) of functions.
5. Instead of `_ = (reminders!).map { reminder in ... }`, I would recommend you just use `for reminder in reminders { ... }`.

#### However…

I think what you're doing is overly complicated.

Notice that `predicateForRemindersInCalendars` takes an *array* of calendars. You can simply pass all your calendars, `cals`, to get a single predicate encompassing all of them, and run a single query:

```
let predicate = eventStore.predicateForRemindersInCalendars(cals)
eventStore.fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate(predicate) { reminders in
    print("Number of reminders: \(reminders?.count ?? 0)")

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.sendChangedNotification()  // refreshes the UI

        completed(configError ?? preferenceError)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the great tips!! I edited my code above and have one more question detailed in my edit...

Comment: @Daniel What problems are you having with that function? There shouldn't be any threading issues since it's only running on one thread.

Comment: you're right, it is working. What isn't working is the displaying of this in the UI. Even though the data structure is correct, the UI sometimes displays the correct number of elements, sometimes too few. Is the refreshing of the UI happening before the data structure is completely built? I thought that because self.sendChangedNotification() was within dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { } this would be taken care of...

Comment: It depends what you do in response to the notification. You must always update your UI (table view, collection view, etc.) at the same time as (i.e. just after) you update your underlying data source. If you are still having issues with this I would recommend posting a new question, as it's straying pretty far from the original topic.

Comment: Ok, will do. Awesome idea about simplifying code. It's crazy, all examples found on the web fetch the reminders one-by-one instead of just passing the whole array in one go. For this suggestion me love you long time!

Comment: Glad I could help :)